# Logging call trace for source code java swing project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have a huge java swing application and I am supposed to understand how the entire project works but I am new to Java swing but I have some knowledge about java. there are over 50 GUI classes in the code. I was wondering if there is any plug-in for eclipse or any other way I can trace the call hierarchy for the project? I tried a plug-in called Intrace, but it didn't work. I was able to install the plugin but it did not show up when i tried to launch the project. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your IDE debugger for monitoring the function call stack. Also you can put break points and check for the call hirarchy for a function. 
Also it's always a good practice to have a logging system in your application. A good library for logging is Log4j by Apache. You can log in different level and place them in functions you believe are involved in the actions, and you can check in the console the order of execution by looking at the order of log printed.